# Nobel Prize in Cognitive Science

Tags: methodology, cognitive

What is the highest award for rewarding someone in cognitive sciences research/applications?

Comment: I removed the opinion-based question (this is not a forum for that purpose), and updated the tags.  Feel free to undo if you wish, but I expect this question will be closed otherwise.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a scientific stack. Perhaps go for Academia.SE.

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge, there is one and only one psychologist who received the Nobel prize: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Kahneman

The prize was awarded for economy.

So, it's possible for cognitive scientists to win the actual Nobel prize if his or her work is relevant to any of the Nobel prize categories.

Maybe there are other laureates whose work could be seen as cognitive science.